# Does anyone know what set this is?

Tags: set-identification

I have recently re-discovered Lego and was looking through my son's old sets. In a box I found this partially assembled "Bug". I don't have the instructions nor the original box so I am unsure what set this is.

If I can figure it out I can get the parts list and instructions and complete it.

[image: Lego Set]

Comment: Could you post a bigger picture?

Answer (score 9):

I believe this to be part of the Insectoid space series,

I think set 6907:

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6907-1

But could also be one of the other 3 sets that contain the stinger.
https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x239&in=S

Comment: Michael, I believe you are correct...I think it is the set # 6969....I will check more thoroughly tonight. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Based on the wings, the magnet on the tail and the legs it must be 6907 indeed.

Comment: Yes, the 6969 has larger legs and only two